# Replace string with numbered list

Tags: awk, sed, grep

Here is the scenario:

- Created a numbered list using an Android Markdown app
- Imported list to Emacs
- For some reason, all numbers beyond 174 have a `[[tel:INT]]` line prefix

  ```
  172.
  173.
  174.
  [[tel:175][175]].
  [[tel:176][176]].
  [[tel:177][177]].
  ```

I want to find each instance of `[[tel:INT]]` and replace it with `175`, `176`, `177`, etc.

**Question:**

Whats the best way to grep/sed/awk this list into order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do...

```
sed -E 's/\[\[.*\[(.*)\]\]/\1/' file

172.         
173.    
174.    
175.     
176.   
177.
```

Comment: This worked great. Added the `-i` flag and it wrote the list exactly how I needed it.

Answer (score 0):

Using **sed**

```
sed -E 's/\[\[tel:([0-9]+)\]\[[0-9]+\]\]/\1/g' tmp.txt
```

Output:

```
172.
173.
174.
175.
176.
177.
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Since the other answers are `sed`:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' input.txt | sort -un
```

Given input file `input.txt`:

```
172.
173.
174.
[[tel:175][175]].
[[tel:176][176]].
[[tel:177][177]].
```

Then:

```
grep -Eo '[0-9]+' input.txt | sort -un
```

Results:

```
172
173
174
175
176
177
```

Comment: I appreciate the stab at this. Resulted in a list of numbers, but not in numerical order:
1
10
100
101
102
103
104
105
106
107
108
109
11
110
111
112
113

Comment: @SeaDude I see... would you mind giving it a go with the extra `-un` flag now just so that this can remain a valid answer.

Comment: Worked as you intended it yes. The part that I left out, was that each line had text after the number. I removed the text in my OP.